# Pass ajax result to HTML paragraph

Tags: html, ajax

I'm probably missing something very obvious since I'm not familiar with ajax and it's been years since I touched html but I have a fairly simple function that calls an API via POST

```
// Predict
$('#btn-predict').click(function () {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);

    // Show loading animation
    $(this).hide();
    $('.loader').show();

    // Make prediction by calling api /predict
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/DiabeticRetinopathy',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            // Get and display the result
            $('.loader').hide();
            $('#result').fadeIn(600);
            $('#result').text(data[0]);
            console.log('Success!');
        },
    });
});
```

And I can see the result in the html if I give it it's own dedicated section like

```
<h3 id="result">
    <span> </span>
</h3>
```

But it's an float and I just wanted something simple like appending it to the end of a static paragraph

```
<p>Model Predictive Probability:<div class="result"></div> </p> <-doesn't work
```

I'm fairly sure that I'm using the wrong syntax somewhere. I can get around it by changing the python script in the backend to actually return the string "Model Predictive Probability: (insert float here)" to the ajax function instead of just returning the float but the end result is going to have several floats all with different strings and there's no way that's the easiest way to go about it

EDIT: I used div class= instead of div id= like an dummy. div id works just fine

Comment: does changing class='result' to id='result' do the trick?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get the `Success!` logged? Does the value just not show up?

Comment: $( ".result" ).append( data[0] )

Comment: `<div>` tag should not in `<p>`

Comment: I am so dumb, DCR is correct, it's id instead of class. That was the problem. Also forgot to clarify, the success! gets logged, it just wasn't actually updating on the browser